# Delete only certain info of the attributes table and not a complete row in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, delete

I want to delete only certain information of certain cells of the attributes table in QGIS and not the complete rows or columns that contain that word. For example, I want to eliminate all the words "glacier" of the field type and the words "O'Higgins" of the field Name but conserve the rest of the row and column information and also in those cells I want to display "Null". How can I do that, is there any expression?

[image]

Comment: What software are you able to use?

Comment: Iwant to performe this in QGIS

Comment: What have you tried by so far ?

Comment: It will help you research this if you realize that you don't want to 'delete' but to 'update'. DELETE is a row-wise removal (only). Searching on 'update' and 'replace' will help.

Comment: Thank you @Vince

Comment: and @Taras, I tried to run an expression in the Fields calculator that allows me to replace those words with Null, for example using regexp_replace("O Higgins" , 'Null'). But It doesn't work and I can't find the correct expression.

Comment: There's a difference between a Null value and a null string (`''`), but this is the sort of thing you need to document *in the Question* (via an [Edit], not as a comment). "It doesn't work" is not a sufficient problem statement -- you need to tell us what it does instead.

Comment: ...and in QGIS the null value is represented by `NULL` in upper case.

Answer (score 5):

Use the field calculator, tell it to update the `Type` field, and use the expression:

```
if(Type='Glacier',NULL,Type)
```

apply that, and repeat for your other use case.

Comment: Thank you @Spacedman. I tried that expression and it works!!!

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, you should accept it (hit the checkmark next to it). Additionally, you can also  upvotes it.